# How to sum groups in Solr?

Tags: solr, group-by, sum

I want to know how to do this like sql in solr ?

```
select sum(Col1) group by Col2,Col3
```

I  could solve the problem  like `select sum(Col1) group by Col2` in solr .( http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent)
can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve this using the [Stats Component](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-stats-component.html) feature which you already mentioned.
For example

```
/select?q=:&stats=true&stats.facet=Col2&stats.field=Col1
```

This way you get the stats block with a grouped `Col2` in the result where you can access the `sum` value for each `Col2`.
But the documentation states that the use of stats.facet is not recommended any more.

> This legacy parameter is not recommended for new users - instead please consider combining stats.field with facet.pivot

But i have to admit that i fail to solve your use case using only the recommended stats.field with facet.pivot.

Answer (score 1):

Solr provides an grouping feature called [field Collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing)
This will allow you to group on a non multivalued field.

Comment: you can combine the fields into one field like col2_col3, which can you give the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: doc1: name=>smith  ,money=>20.0 ,country=>"USA",age=>"25"       doc2: name=>robert ,money=>30.0 ,country=>"china",age=>"22"       doc2: name=>andiy  ,money=>60.0 ,country=>"USA",age=>"22"           doc2: name=>mark  ,money=>25.0 ,country=>"USA",age=>"22"                 I need the result like:                                             20.0, "USA","25";                                         30.0,"cina", "22";                                               85.0 "USA","22"  is it possible? such as the query below : &stats=true&stats.field=money&stats.facet=country  and stats.facet=age ?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to group here ?? you can combine the country age field or group on one field and sort within the group. You can group by queries as well.

Comment: Thanks . Yes , I wnat to combine the country and age field .. may be combine is the only way to solve the problem. which i don't want to use it. Because I have other field to gourp by too.. If i use comine ,too many combination...

Comment: Please add comments for -ve voting !!