# group by fields in solr

Tags: solr, group-by

I have solr index for the below table structure

```
SMS(cost int, operator varchar(30), user_id int, created_at date)
```

is it possible in solr to find sum(cost) group by (operator and user_id).
in other word, is it possible to return the same result of the below sql query in solr

```
select sum(cost),operator, user_id from sms group by operator, user_id;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum groups in Solr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315573/how-to-sum-groups-in-solr)

Answer (score 0):

try with below

```
&stats=on
&stats.field=cost
&stats.facet=operator
```

The more info on stats 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component